# Verificación ReCaptcha de Google

Tags: javascript, html, captcha

Estoy tratando de integrar el `recaptcha` de Google en un formulario. He conseguido que funcione pero el problema esta en que, pulse o no pulse sobre el `captcha`, el formulario se envía igualmente. Me gustaría validarlo por medio de JavaScript ya que he visto en la documentación que es posible. Ajunto mi código por si es de utilidad:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=es'></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="#" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre...">
        <input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido...">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Le9zh8UAAAAAKn-kpHg2Ls7MfqsiOznS7Pp94ja"></div>
        <input type="submit" name="enviar" placeholder="ENVIAR">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Y aqui dos imagenes de como se me ve el captcha:
[image: Primera pantalla de captcha]
[image: Segunda pantalla de captcha]

Comment: Hola amigo una pregunta ando haciendo lo mismo, me podrian colaborar por favor gracias el script y el html lo colocaste en la misma pag?

Comment: Las respuestas resuelven la pregunta a la perfección. Aun así remarcar que es importante validar desde el servidor que se ha resuelto correctamente, ya que validar desde javascript (cliente) jamás es seguro, siempre es vulnerable a que el usuario lo cambie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prueba con este código.

Hay que indicar al formulario que tiene que validarse utilizando el evento "onSubmit" e indicando la función javascript debe lanzarse al pulsar en enviar.

Con respecto al captcha se hace uso de la función "getResponse" que indica si ha sido verificado o no

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title>HTML Tutorial</title>

  <head>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
  </head>

<body>

  <form action="#" method="POST" onsubmit="miFuncion()">
    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre...">
    <input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido...">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Le9zh8UAAAAAKn-kpHg2Ls7MfqsiOznS7Pp94ja"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" placeholder="ENVIAR">
  </form>

<script>
  function miFuncion() {
    var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();

    if(response.length == 0){
      alert("Captcha no verificado")
    } else {
      alert("Captcha verificado");
    }
  }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ha funcionado a la perfección :)

Answer (score 4):

El [Captcha de Google](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/invisible.html) tiene un ***método*** `data-callback="...(js function)..."` para llamar una funcion ***javascript*** una vez que a pasado la prueba, el siguiente ejemplo muestra como activar el boton ***submit*** una vez que a pasado la prueba del Captcha:

```js
function enabledSubmit(response) {
 document.getElemenstByName('enviar')[0].disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

<form action="#" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre...">
    <input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido...">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Le9zh8UAAAAAKn-kpHg2Ls7MfqsiOznS7Pp94ja" data-callback="enabledSubmit"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" placeholder="ENVIAR" disabled>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas, me orientaron para habilitar el envío del formulario solo cuando se validara el recaptcha, el truco es poner el onsubmit a retornar un valor según la respuesta del captcha:

```
   <form action="#" onsubmit="return miFuncion(this)" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre...">
    <input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido...">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Le9zh8UAAAAAKn-kpHg2Ls7MfqsiOznS7Pp94ja" data-callback="enabledSubmit"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" placeholder="ENVIAR" disabled>
</form>

function miFuncion(a) {
    var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();

    if(response.length == 0){
        alert("Captcha no verificado");
        return false;
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      alert("Captcha verificado");
      return true;
    }
  }
```