# Inhabilitar y habilitar botón en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy validando un formulario con `Javascript`, dicho formulario contiene un `recaptcha` al cual, me gustaría poder habilitar un botón de enviar luego de que el `recaptcha` y los demás campos sean verificados, conseguí en el siguiente [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67156/verificaci%C3%B3n-recaptcha-de-google) una manera de poder verificar el captcha, funciona pero al agregar el atributo `disabled` (como la segunda respuesta del enlace) en el input, con solo hacer click derecho e inspeccionar página, y borrar dicho atributo, se habilita el botón nuevamente.

Lo que me gustaría es saber como es posible habilitar el botón de enviar solo cuando el campo de `usuario`, `contraseña` y el `recaptcha` estén llenos, y si estos campos no contienen nada, el botón seguir desactivado.

Utilice el método `.prop()` pero no desactiva el botón si este campo se encuentra vacío.

- **Javascript:**

```
    // Validación de ingreso
    $(".validarIngreso").change(function(){
        var usuario = $("#usuario").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var error = $("#error");

        error.text("");

        if(usuario != "")
        {
            var caracteres = usuario.length;
            var expresion = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/; /*NO INCLUYA CARACTERES ESPECIALES*/

            if(caracteres > 6)
            {
                error.append("<i class='fas fa-times'></i> Usuario incorrecto, ingresó más de 6 caracteres.");
            }
            else if(!expresion.test(usuario))
            {
                error.append("<i class='fas fa-times'></i> Por favor, no ingrese caracteres especiales en el usuario.");
            }
            else
            {
                error.text("");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $("#enviar").prop("disabled", true);
        }

        if(password != "")
        {
            var caracteres = password.length;
            var expresion = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/; /*NO INCLUYA CARACTERES ESPECIALES*/

            if(caracteres < 6)
            {
                error.append("<i class='fas fa-times'></i> Contraseña incorrecto, ingresó menos de 6 caracteres.");
            }
            else if(!expresion.test(password))
            {
                error.append("<i class='fas fa-times'></i> Por favor, no ingrese caracteres especiales en la contraseña.");
            }
            else
            {
                error.text("");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $("#enviar").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });

    function enabledSubmit(response) {
        $('#enviar')[0].disabled = false;
    }
```

- **Html**

```
<form method="POST">
    <!-- usuario -->
    <div class="group validarIngreso"> 
        <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" maxlength="6" required>
        <span class="highlight"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <label><i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i> USUARIO</label>
    </div>

    <!-- contraseña -->
    <div class="group validarIngreso">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" pattern="(?=.*[a-z]).{6,}" required>
        <span class="highlight"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <label><i class="fas fa-key"></i> CONTRASEÑA</label>
    </div>

    <span class="text-danger p-2" id="error"></span>

    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcUXbkUAAAAAIwK4Jh4IuFT9j0WgHsHzl0IJPac" data-callback="enabledSubmit"></div> 
    </div>

    <!-- botones del modal -->
    <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-entrar" id="enviar">INGRESAR</button>
</form>
```

Comment: La única podrías hacer que se genere el botón después de que ya hayas hecho la validación

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realicé una función para que tengas una idea de cómo hacer lo que deseas. Solo tendrías que acomodarlo a tu gusto, quizás agregándole cosas que quisieras.

En esta función vamos a utilizar:

1. `preventDefault()`: Previene el evento predeterminado. En este caso enviar el formulario.
2. `submit()`: Envía los datos del formulario.
3. `addEventListener()`: Registra un evento a un objeto en específico.

Lo que realizamos en el código es lo siguiente:

1. Obtenemos los elementos **input usuario** e **input contraseña** , el botón **submit** y el formulario.
2. Capturamos el evento del botón con `addEventListener()` para que al hacer clic realice una acción.
3. Creamos la función que va a utilizar el botón.
4. Utilizamos `preventDefault()` para cancelar el evento predeterminado.
5. Utilizamos un `if` para validar.

Dentro del `if` validaremos los `inputs` *usuario* y *contraseña* si contienen lo deseado.

Si contienen lo deseado utilizaremos el `form.submit()` para enviar la misma función que prevenimos antes al dar clic en el botón.

Y en caso contrario mandaremos un `alert()` para avisar al usuario de lo que esta realizando mal.

```js
var usuario = document.getElementById("usuario");
var pass = document.getElementById("password");
var boton = document.getElementById("enviar");
var form = document.getElementById("form-user-data-login");

boton.addEventListener("click", validar);
function validar(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (usuario.value && pass.value) {
    // Agregas la validación del «ReCaptcha».
    form.submit();
    // Envías el formulario en caso de cumplir el «IF»
  } else {
    alert("Debes completar todos los datos para continuar");
    // Acá puedes usar otra cosa o simplemente no hacer nada,
    // tal vez, imprimir un texto en algún sitio o así.
  }
}
```

Debes agregar al `if` la validación del **Recaptcha** y si deseas, cambiar el `alert()`.

También te recomiendo que el **RegEx** que utilizas en la caja *contraseña* y el `maxlength` que usas en la caja *usuario* lo pases a **JS**.

**Nota:** Podrías eliminar el `type="submit"` del botón y quitar la primera línea de la función ya que enviaremos los datos utilizando el elemento `form` y la función `submit()`.